# github composite action error: An action could not be found at the URI

Tags: github, github-actions

Created a github repo for a composite action, in the root of the repo i have a `action.yml` with the below code:

```
name: "semver-tag-release"
description: "Creates a semver release/tag on push to master"

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:

      - name: Automated Version Bump
        id: version-bump
        uses: 'phips28/gh-action-bump-version@master'
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.BYPASS }}
        with:
          skip-tag: 'false'
```

I added it to the existing push pipeline

```
name: Push

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: 'actions/checkout@v2'
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
          fetch-depth: 50

      - name: composite-semver-tag-release
        uses: company/composite-semver-tag-release@0.1.4
```

When i run the push pipeline i get the error:

```
Download action repository 'company/composite-semver-tag-release@0.1.4' (SHA:dd280586e6409ee58fe59bd95d63dbefa19e2e13)
Error: An action could not be found at the URI 'https://api.github.com/repos/company/composite-semver-tag-release/tarball/dd280586e6409ee58fe59bd95d63dbefa19e2e13'
```

Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Comment: Does the SHA in the error message point to the tag 0.1.4? If so, does the action.yml exist at that revision?

Comment: Hey, yes SHA matches downloaded the extract of the tag which is just the repo so action.yml is in root of the extract folder

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, did you find a sulotion?

Comment: My issue was that had the composite repo set to private. You have to make a public repo to use it as a composite (which im i dont really like to be honest)..

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that had the composite repo set to private. You have to make a public repo to use it as a composite (which im i dont really like to be honest)..

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action#prerequisites

```
Prerequisites
Before you begin, you'll create a repository on GitHub.com.

Create a new public repository on GitHub.com.
```